# How to use Spring integration sftp outbound gateway with java config

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm new to Spring integration sftp.Now,I want to download files from multiple directories.then it seems that SFTP Outbound Gateway is my chocie,but I only find examples using XML config.How can this be done using Java config?
My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory(){
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        ...
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(defaultSftpSessionFactory);
    }
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel",autoStartup = "false", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    ...
    }
    @Bean(name = "lsGateway")
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handlerLs(){
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),"ls","payload");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-gateway"));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface OutboundGatewayOption {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public List<Boolean> lsGetAndRmFiles(String dir);

}
```

but when I start the app,nothing happens,where is wrong?

----update---
My test class

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@Slf4j
@MessageEndpoint
public class SftpConfigTest{
    @Autowired
    private OutboundGatewayOption gatewayOption;
    @Test
    public void test(){
        gatewayOption.lsGetAndRmFiles("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "nothing happens". It appears you have two ways to trigger the LS request - a messaging gateway (which you have to call) and an inbound channel adapter, which has `autoStartup = "false"` - it won't invoke the gateway until it is started.

Also, when using that as the trigger, you will need an output channel on the SFTP gateway (where to send the result). When invoking the gateway by calling the messaging gateway, the result will be returned to the gateway (since the SFTP gateway has no output channel).

Comment: yeah, when I didn't use LS gateway,I use messageSource.receive() to receive files.but when I use LS gateway,I don't konw how to receive files.And the outBoundGatewayOption seems don't work.when I use @Autowire In my configuration class,I could not get the bean. how can I use it as a trigger?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528316/how-polling-works-for-ftp-inbound-channel-adapter-considering-max-message-per-po/42535069#42535069) - it's ftp instead of sftp but the same applies; it has additional logic to limit the number of files fetched.

Comment: Sorry to reply late,when I autowired the OutboundGatewayOption,I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.Now I don't have a IntegrationFlow Bean,is that matters?

Comment: In 5.0 it will be integrated; for earlier versions, you need an additional dependency: `org.springframework.integration;spring-integration-java-dsl:1.2.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: And now I have spring-integration-java-dsl dependency in my pom.xml.In my test Class I autowired the OutboundGateway,But I get a No qualifying bean of type [com.creditcloud.calculator.config.OutboundGatewayOption] found for dependency [com.creditcloud.calculator.config.OutboundGatewayOption],it seems that I didn't define it as a Bean?But in the links you give me, that works.where is wrong?

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#messaging-gateway-annotation) you need `@IntegrationComponentScan` on your configuration class to detect `@MessagingGateway`. It's not in the answer I pointed you to because that's a Spring Boot application which automatically adds that annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explain.And I take a holiday last three days .My quession had been solved.