# Spring Integration read files from dynamic multiple directories

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I am using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html) and Spring forum. The process works if remote directory is set as "foo" but it doesn't accept expression (`foo/\*/*`) that can read any number of files/folders under "foo". Completely lost!

```
    @Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("foo/*/*"));
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}
```

Is there a library that can provide programmatic control to deal with (s)ftp operations that work well with spring(-boot). The documentation is huge, and for a FTP beginner like me, I'm not getting anywhere soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an (S)FTP [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) with a recursive `MGET` command for that. The inbound channel adapter (synchronizer) doesn't support pulling directory trees.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell.

Comment: There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528316/how-polling-works-for-ftp-inbound-channel-adapter-considering-max-message-per-po/42535069#42535069).